# Converting 8 bits to a scaled 12 bits equivalent

Tags: c, algorithm, converters

I need to convert an 8 bit number (0 - 255 or #0 - #FF) to its 12 bit equivalent (0 - 4095 or #0 - #FFF)

I am not wanting to do just a straight conversion of the same number. I am wanting to represent the same scale, but in 12 bits.

**For example:-**

0xFF in 8 bits should convert to 0xFFF in 12 bits

0x0 in 8 bits    should convert to 0x0 in 12 bits

0x7F in 8 bits should convert to 0x7FF in 12 bits

0x24 in 8 bit should convert to 0x249  in 12 bits

Are there any specific algorithms or techniques that I should be using?

I am coding in C

Comment: Can you approximate by shifting left and/or subtracting 1(or adding)? Like 110 in 3bit to 1100 in 4 bit which are 6 to 12 for maximums of 7 to 15(14 by subtracting).

Comment: I might just get away with that....I noticed this may be a solution as I was performing the calculations above. These values will be used in to drive LED lighting, so complete accuracy is not super important. I would need to test to see if it made a difference, so I am interested to hear if there are other ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: In that case, left-shifting by 4 sounds like the quickest simplest approach.  That will lead to an inaccuracy of about 1%, which is unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: I think your examples for 0x7f and 0x24 are incorrect if you're looking for a linear relationship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `x << 4 | x >> 4`.

This has been updated by the OP, changed from x << 4 + x >> 4

Comment: +1, just replicating the most significant bits of the 8bit number into the low 4 bits of the 12 bit number gives results that are usually very close to a solution using division. And it handles all corner cases for 0 and 0xff as well.

Comment: My first instinct was that this was wrong.  Then I did my own derivation and realized it was exactly the same as this result.  I'd explain it like this:  x_12 = x_8 * 0xFFF / 0xFF which is algebraically correct but, in integer arithmetic, will come up short due to truncation of the fraction in the division.  You'll end up multiplying by 16 instead of (approximately) 16.06.  The first term `x << 4` multiplies by 16, and the second term `x >> 4` (which is 1/16 of x) approximates how much you lost by not including the 0.06.

Comment: How would you change this to handle 8-bit to 10-bit scaling? x << 2 | x >> 2; ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to go through a larger domain then this may help:

```
b = a * ((1 << 12) - 1) / ((1 << 8) - 1)
```

It is ugly but **preserves scaling** almost as requested. Of course you can put constants.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
x = x ?((x + 1) << 4) - 1 :0
```

Answer (score 0):

I use mathematical equation `y=mx+c`
Assuming low range of values is zero.
You can scale your data by a factor of m (Multiple for increasing range and divide for decreasing)
Ex.
My ADC data was 12 bit. Range in integer =0 to 4095
I want to shrink this data in range 0 to 255.

```
m=(y2-y1/x2-x1)
m=(4095-0/255-0)
m=16.05 = 16
```

So data received in 12 bits is divided by 16 to convert to 8 bits.
This conversion is linear in nature.

Hope this is also a good idea.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehm9Q.png)

Comment: I think the question is asking about the other direction:  8-bit to 12-bit.  If you multiply an 8-bit integer by 16, you'll get close but there will be systematic error due to rounding down.  For example, 0xFF * 16 = 0xFF0, but we want 0xFFF.

Comment: Yes you are right @AdrianMcCarthy. and i did not find any issues till now (just used for mathematical calc. so only though of keeping higher value within the range).