# Scale this value from 11-Bit to 14-Bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have data coming in as two separate bytes. Functionally, this data is combined to create an 11-bit unsigned number. I need to scale it up to 14-bit, then split it apart again into two bytes and transmit it. I used this thread as a reference: [Converting 8 bits to a scaled 12 bits equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220326/converting-8-bits-to-a-scaled-12-bits-equivalent)

Here's a twist: 
The most significant bits are not used in either case - neither in the incoming or outgoing data. So bits 0-6 are valid, bit 7 is not. If N=valid value, and X=invalid value, the incoming data looks like:

MSB: XXXXNNNN
LSB: XNNNNNNN

And the outgoing data needs to look like:

MSB: XNNNNNNN
LSB: XNNNNNNN

Here is what I came up with. Can anyone suggest anything more accurate or see an issue with what I am doing? Note: yes, the LSB gets put into the transmit buffer first by design.

```
uint16_t FullVal = 0;
uint8_t LSB_Temp = 0;

LSB_Temp = ( Msg_Buff[Buff_Tail_Indx].RX_Data[2] << 1 ) | ( Msg_Buff[Buff_Tail_Indx].RX_Data[2] >> 1 );     //Shift 7-bit LSB value left then fill lsb
FullVal = ( Msg_Buff[Buff_Tail_Indx].RX_Data[1] << 8 ) | LSB_Temp;                                      //Or together bytes
FullVal = (( FullVal << 3 ) | ( FullVal >> 3 ));                                                        //Scale 11-bit to 14-bit (missing bit is LSB bit 7)
TX_Data[1] = ( FullVal & 0x007F );                                                                      //Grab LSB, shift right to scale to 7 bits
TX_Data[2] = ( FullVal >> 8 ) & 0x00FF;                                                             //Grab MSB
```

Comment: What is not accurate about your current method?

Comment: Maybe you should break your problem down into 3 parts — (1) converting input bytes into a 11-bit value; (2) scaling; and (3) converting a value into output bytes. The scaling part is incorrect for sure; not sure about the two other parts. If you care about some part the most, leave just it in the question, and delete the other two. Just a suggestion.

Comment: `Y = X << n | X >> n` appears suspicious to me, what do you intend by? From the question you reference there's `x << 4 | x >> 4` – which is fine *only* for swapping nibbles of a 8-bit-byte. With n = 1 you'd move second least significant bit into the very least one and second most significant bit into the very most one, while those in the middle overlap with quite some higher chance of getting one...

Comment: *'the most significant bits in the least significant bytes (bit 7) are not used in either case.'* – don't really get it – now which exactly are the relevant bits? Something like bits 0-3 in byte 0 forming the most significant four ones of the final value and bits 0-6 in byte 1 the the least significant 7 ones?

Comment: "the most significant bits in the least significant bytes (bit 7) are not used in either case" Meaning what? Do you have value bits going ...b5, b6, dummy, b7...? As in inserting a bit in the middle of the data. Is the actual data payload 11 bits or 10 bits? Is it signed, is it unsigned?

Comment: Other than that, just multiply with 2^14 / 2^11 = 8.

Comment: If this is working code, and you would like a code review consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a code review on working code, as opposed to help with solving a problem  There are better places to post this.

Comment: @Lundin: there are two bytes coming in. For the least significant byte, bit 7 is a dummy byte. Bits 0-6 are valid.

Comment: Could you  please add some examples of inputs and expected results? What happened to `TX_Data[0]`?

Comment: @nobby You still didn't answer if it is signed or unsigned. Please post real code with actual variable declarations.

Comment: Would output data just fill the 7 least significant bits in both bytes?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Without getting too far into the weeds of the details of the source of the data, I am observing what are essentially "rounding errors" where my value jumps when it rolls past the disused bit (bit 7) in the LSB.

Comment: Did you test your code? What is the output supposed to be if `RX_Data[2]` is 16 (0x10) and `RX_Data[1]` is 0? Then the `LSB_Temp` assignment sets `LSB_Temp` to 0x50, the first `FullVal` assignment sets it to 0x50, and the second `FullVal` assignment sets it to 0x28A. That does not look at all like scaling a value from 11 bits to 14.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that bit 7 in each of the two incoming bytes is zero when they are received, or do they need to be cleared? In the outgoing bytes, do those bits need to be zero or can they be any value?

Comment: Please post the encoding, decoding and scaling questions as three separate questions with clearly-defined inputs and outputs.  For the scaling, is it OK to just multiply by 8, or do you actually need  4095 to map to 32767?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** While the initial answer went through all the way of building a combined value you actually can do more efficiently by creating the values directly, skipping this combined value!

At first scaling occurs as follows:

```
scaled = value * targetRange / sourceRange;
```

In given case:

```
scaled = value * (1 << 14) / (1 << 11)
```

which resolves to simply

```
value << 3
```

As there's only a bitshift involved you can apply it on the two bytes independently, then you simply get:

```
uint8_t targetLow = sourceLow << 3;
// or, if it is relevant to clear out the most significant bit
// i.e. you need to guarantee a zero MSB:
uint8_t targetLow = sourceLow << 3 & 0x7f;
```

This simply shifts out the most significant bits. These, though need to be integrated in the high byte!

```
uint8_t targetHigh = sourceHigh << 3 | sourceLow >> 4;
// or, if surplus most significant bits are not guaranteed to be zero:
uint8_t targetHigh = sourceHigh << 3 | sourceLow >> 4 & 0x07;
// ... and you additionally want to guarantee a zero MSB yourself:
uint8_t targetHigh = sourceHigh << 3 & 0x7f | sourceLow << 4 & 0x07;
```

That's it already...

---

---

Leaving the general part of for creating combined values for informational purpose:

<s>Your explanation isn't fully clear where the relevant bits now actually reside, apart from all of them at least occupying the least significant bits in their respective byte.</s> Since your edit of the question: Replace `lowBits` with 7 and `highBits` with 4 – or better: define these as *constants*.

If you want to extract the least significant bits from a byte you can do so by simply masking out the upper bits; for this purpose you need a mask with relevant significant bits being 1 and the others being 0; for a general `char` you can do so by:

```
unsigned char mask = ~((unsigned char)-1 << n);
```

or alternatively

```
unsigned char mask = (unsigned char)-1 << (CHAR_BIT - n);
```

where `n` in both cases is the number of relevant least significant bits. All that remains for you then is:

```
unsigned char extracted = value & mask;
```

If you want to drop `m` least significant bits and then use the next `n` least significant ones you would do as

```
unsigned char extracted = value >> m & mask;
```

with the same mask as before.

Now assuming you have done this for the two bytes in your message. You now want to combine both of. For this purpose you need to convert the extracted bits as a 16-bit value. So you need to cast your values appropriately (or store in 16-bit variables right from the start). Assuming `k` bits reside in the lower byte then you combine both values simply by:

```
uint16_t combined = (uint16_t)extractedHigh << k | (uint16_t)extractedLow;
```

Now you have your final value. Scaling then occurs just as always:

```
scaled = value * targetRange / sourceRange;
```

However you need to make sure no overflow occurs; with scaling a 11-bit to a 14-bit value you might end up with a maximum value having 25 significant bits; so we can safely use 32 bits to calculate the intermediate value:

```
uint16_t scaled = (uint32_t)combined * (1 << 14) / (1 << 11);
```

Well, OK, in this concrete case we can optimise yet a bit; of course the quotient in given case is simply `1<<3` (*2^14 / 2^11 = 2^3*), and multiplying by `1<<n` is just the same as directly shifting by `n`, so in your concrete case you can simply have:

```
uint16_t scaled = combined << 3; // no intermediate 32-bit necessary...
```

Now all combined:

```
uint16_t extractedHigh = (uint8_t)byteHigh & ~((uint8_t)-1 << bitsHigh);
uint16_t extractedLow  = (uint8_t)byteLow  & ~((uint8_t)-1 << bitsLow );
uint16_t scaled = (extractedHigh << bitsLow | extractedLow) << 3;
```

Note that this scales correctly no matter if your input data is signed or unsigned – **as long as** you do not care about the two most significant bits within the scaled value for signed input. You *would* for signed values if you e.g. wanted to log them; then you would need sign extension; simple and efficient:

```
int16_t signedScaled = (int16_t)(scaled << 2) >> 2;
```

Unfortunately it is implementation defined if right shift for signed values is arithmetic or logical shift; if you want to be fully portable you might want to consider both cases:

```
#if -1 >> 1 == -1
    int16_t signedScaled = (int16_t)(scaled << 2) >> 2;
#else
    uint16_t bit = scaled & 1 << 13;
    scaled = bit << 1 | bit << 2;
    int16_t signedScaled = scaled;
#endif
```

Note that this assumes two's complement! Other formats are not covered.

Building the output bytes then is simple, too, we can start with the *unsigned* scaled value:

```
uint8_t byteLow = scaled;
uint8_t byteHigh = scaled >> bitsLow;
```

This is the efficient variant, not caring for the most significant bits within the low byte; if these *need* to be set to 0 then you need to mask the surplus bits out:

```
uint8_t byteLow = scaled & ~((uint8_t)-1 << bitsLow);
```

You don't need to mask the bits for the high byte, these are 0 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we call the numbers including the bit 7 dummy byte for "raw" and the mathematical number with that one removed "value".

- Store what's saved bit 7 somewhere.
- Shift everything above bit down 1 bit to form a 11 bit value.
- Scale to 14 bits by multiplying by (2^14 / 2^11) = 8.
- For a new 14 bit number that includes the previous value of bit 7.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define GARBAGE_BIT (1u << 7)

int main (void)
{
  uint16_t some_11_bit = 0x765 | (1u<<7); // some raw number
  printf("11 bit raw:   %X\n", some_11_bit);

  uint16_t garbage_bit = some_11_bit & GARBAGE_BIT;

  // convert to 11 bit value
  uint16_t above_garbage = some_11_bit & 0x700u;
  uint16_t below_garbage = some_11_bit & 0x07Fu;
  some_11_bit = ((above_garbage>>1) | below_garbage);
  printf("11 bit value: %X\n", some_11_bit);

  // scale to 14 bits
  uint16_t new_14_bit = 8 * some_11_bit;
  printf("14 bit value: %X\n", new_14_bit);

  above_garbage = (new_14_bit<<1) & 0x3F00;
  below_garbage = new_14_bit & 0x07Fu;
  new_14_bit = above_garbage | garbage_bit | below_garbage;
  printf("14 bit raw:   %X\n", new_14_bit);
}
```

Output:

```
11 bit raw:   7E5
11 bit value: 3E5
14 bit value: 1F28
14 bit raw:   3EA8
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, that's in my opinion makes a significantly more readable code, is letting the compiler to do all the hard work by using the C language bit-fields feature.

Define the structure of your data using bit-fields and unions:

```
#define SCALE_FACTOR  8 // 2^14/2^11
#define USABLE_BITS   7

// Assuming the CPU architecture is little endian
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t low       : 7;  // LSB first
        uint16_t reserved1 : 1;
        uint16_t high      : 4;
        uint16_t reserved2 : 4;
    } bits;
    uint8_t d[2];
    uint16_t u;
} __attribute__((packed)) In_11BitData;

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t low       : 7;  // LSB first
        uint16_t reserved1 : 1;
        uint16_t high      : 7;
        uint16_t reserved2 : 1;
    } bits;
    uint8_t d[2];
    uint16_t u;
} __attribute__((packed)) Out_14BitData;
```

Then use this to do your calculation:

```
int main()
{
    // 0x17e5 = 0b0001'0111'1110'0101
    In_11BitData in = { .d = { 0xe5, 0x17 } };
   
    uint16_t value = (in.bits.high << USABLE_BITS) | in.bits.low;
    value *= SCALE_FACTOR;

    Out_14BitData out;
    out.bits.low = value;
    out.bits.high = value >> USABLE_BITS;

    printf("In:    0x%04x\n", in.u);
    printf("Value: 0x%04x\n", value);
    printf("Out:   0x%04x\n", out.u);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In:    0x17e5
Value: 0x1f28
Out:   0x3e28
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/z/qfojdjoqW)

Note: As correctly noted in the comments, C standard doesn't guarantee that bit fields are ordered starting from LSB. So this code isn't strictly portable. But de facto, this is the case with most compilers I ever encountered. Also, if using C++, a static_assert verifying the order can be added.

Comment: Hm... Bitfields can be problematic; it is implementation defined if they are filled starting at the most or least significant bit (only bit groups defined one after another need to neighbour one another in the representation as well) , so even if the endianess is clear then still the compiler comes into play! Admitted, all the major ones start at the LSB, but to be fully portable we might rather not want to use them...

Comment: @Aconcagua I never seen an architecture that had it start from MSB, but in any case, that is easily verifiable at compile time if using C++ (you can use constexpr and static_assert). In any case, I personally would sacrifice this theoretical portability in favor of code clarity.

Comment: We're C, not C++ (and C++ would result in undefined behaviour for accessing union members not being the active ones...). Well, such a test might be constructed in C as well (based on creating arrays with negative size), but yes, yours is an acceptable point of view ;) Just that in given case the solution can be so much simpler...

Comment: @Aconcagua How do you do such a test at compile time in C? I'm curious.

Comment: Hm... Too much C++, too little C recently – I missed the important point that `const` global variables are *not* considered compile time constants (other than in C++)... The [try](https://godbolt.org/z/34x63hP49) would have been a nice one ;)

Comment: Ah, by the way, you can leave names out for bits that are not used, i.e. `uint8_t : 1;` instead of `uint8_t reserved : 1;` – just for the case you might not have been aware of; I consider that superior, but of course that's a matter of taste.

Comment: *'Note: [...] C++'* ah, well, strictly spoken this solution would invoke undefined behaviour; in C++, you're not allowed to access a union member that's not the active one (apart from making it active by assignment, of course) – but then again most compilers support that as an *extension* ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua tbh, I completely don't understand why the standard doesn't define the bit fields order. That makes this awesome feature way less useful.

Comment: Oh, *that* I fully agree on!!! Though if we only do in C++ we break compatibility with C, and C people are pretty scared (paranoia sometimes?) from breaking existing code. One of the rare exceptions they indeed risked was on removing `gets` from the standard, but we'll likely have to wait quite some while until such thing happens next time ;) On the other hand I don't understand either why C++ standard won't allow type punning if only POD types are part of the union in question...